# Visual Fox Pro: Saving and Showing a Photo

Tags: visual-foxpro

I created this

A button on click will do:

```
lcFileName=GETPICT()
**then i append that to a table field
APPEND BLANK
replace picture.name WITH lcFileName
```

then this is for the init of the image holder

```
goto top **Just testing, so i only aligned the data to the very first one
thisform.image1.Picture = picture.name
```

The problem is this does not save or copy the image i selected into a new folder which i still do not know how to and the image inst showing in the image holder.

thanks

Comment: Are you saying that after the user specifies the picture, you want to make a copy of the picture file somewhere else? If that's it, just use the COPY FILE command.

Comment: ok i researched that and it worked! feel free to add that to answers and ill check it as answered @TamarE.Granor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COPY FILE to make a copy of the picture file.